# class java.lang.RuntimeException/Scala class file does not contain Scala annotation

Tags: scala, compilation, annotations

I'm trying to execute a scala code using scala 2.10.2, the code uses some jar libraries compiled with sbt.

I get the following error:

```
scala: error while loading Order, class file '..\prestashop-scala-client-0.2.4\target\prestasac-0.2.4.jar(co/orderly/prestasac/representations/Order.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/Scala class file does not contain Scala annotation)
```

Sources of the prestasac-0.2.4.jar are on github: [Order.class](https://github.com/orderly/prestashop-scala-client/blob/master/src/main/scala/co/orderly/prestasac/representations/Order.scala)

Is there something to do to fix this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the source for the Order class? It might provide useful information, e.g. could be related to [this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5165).

Comment: Ok i've added the link to the sources on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the library is configured to compile against Scala 2.9.1. Major versions of Scala are not binary compatible.

I put the necessary SBT changes here: https://github.com/mpartel/prestashop-scala-client/commit/e9a1df40bfe35518aaebac899e438b9b6fa6d728